# Why is there seg fault when I initialize my class in the for loop?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

My code used to work, but now it starts giving seg fault errors. Commenting out input.push_back(Atom(temp[1], stod(temp[2]), stod(temp[3]), stod(temp[4]), stod(temp[8]))) stops it. I run it on bash on windows 10, and take the ethanol mol2 file as an input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

double Coulomb_k = 8.9875517873681764e9;

struct Atom{
    string name;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double energy;
    Atom(string n, double a, double b, double c, double d){
        name = n;
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
        energy = d;
    };
    void printer(){
        cout << "name: " << name << " pos x: " << x << " pos y: " << y << " pos z: " << z <<  " the energy: " << energy;    
    }
};

void mol2(std::istream& stream){
    vector <Atom> input;
    string a;
    //skipping all the crap in the beginning
    getline(stream, a);
    getline(stream, a);
    getline(stream, a);
    istringstream iss(a);
    std::vector<string> top_numbers{istream_iterator<string>{iss}, istream_iterator<string>{}};
    cout << top_numbers[0] << endl;
    //skipping more crap
    getline(stream, a);
    getline(stream, a);
    stream >> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < stoi(top_numbers[0]); i++){
        getline(stream, a);
        istringstream iss1(a);
        std::vector<string> temp{istream_iterator<string>{iss1}, istream_iterator<string>{}};
        input.push_back(Atom(temp[1], stod(temp[2]), stod(temp[3]), stod(temp[4]), stod(temp[8])));
    }

}

int main(){
    mol2(cin);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
ethanol
9   8    1
SMALL
USER_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1         -1.4803   -0.4530    1.4403 C.3       1 UNK         0.1199 
      2 C2         -2.7108   -1.3517    1.5701 C.3       1 UNK        -0.1753 
      3 H3         -2.7552   -2.0859    0.7650 H         1 UNK         0.0698 
      4 H4         -2.7120   -1.8917    2.5176 H         1 UNK         0.0698 
      5 H5         -3.6265   -0.7616    1.5273 H         1 UNK         0.0698 
      6 O6         -0.3206   -1.2582    1.5006 O.3       1 UNK        -0.6589 
      7 H7         -1.4579    0.2880    2.2417 H         1 UNK         0.0432 
      8 H8         -1.5011    0.0948    0.4962 H         1 UNK         0.0432 
      9 H9          0.4535   -0.6787    1.4172 H         1 UNK         0.4187 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1    
     2    1    6 1    
     3    1    7 1    
     4    1    8 1    
     5    2    3 1    
     6    2    4 1    
     7    2    5 1    
     8    6    9 1    
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE
     1 UNK         1 GROUP             0       ****    0 ROOT
```

Comment: If you step through the program in your debugger, you should be able to see what is going on and why it is crashing (probably something with `temp` and the indexing into it).

Comment: What is the size of `temp`?

Comment: I'd start with verifying that all tead operations happen to be successful. I guess they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As crashmstr said, it was the temp that was causing the problem. I fixed it by modifying the code as such (added a few variables, stored directly into them, and initiated the class using them):

```
vector<Atom> mol2(std::istream& stream){
    vector <Atom> input;
    string a, name, b, c, d;
    double x, y, z, e;
    //skipping all the crap in the beginning
    getline(stream, a);
    getline(stream, a);
    getline(stream, a);
    istringstream iss(a);
    std::vector<string> top_numbers{istream_iterator<string>{iss}, istream_iterator<string>{}};
    cout << top_numbers[0] << endl;
    //skipping more crap
    getline(stream, a);
    getline(stream, a);
    stream >> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < stoi(top_numbers[0]); i++){
        cin >> a >> name >> x >> y >> z >> b >> c >> d >> e;
        input.push_back(Atom(name, x, y, z, e));
    }
    return input;
}
```